# Can I change a style of multiple components with one toggle

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to achieve day/night feature with a click of a toggle on my web app.

I know how to add it to a single component with my nav menu lets say,
but I need to add it to multiple components.

One of the solutions I found is to use `ng-deep` but it feels a bit wrong to do it that way in the main CSS.

Another solution I have figured out is to create a `service` and subscribe to the toggle in each of the components, but again that feels like an overkill.

My questions is: **Can I change a style of multiple components with one toggle?**

Would prefer not to use JS.

Currently, my `app.component` looks like this

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Optimus Engine';
  version = 'Latest';

  day = true;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {

  }

  dayNight() {

    if (!this.day) {
      this.element.nativeElement.classList.add('night');
    }

    if (this.day) {
      this.element.nativeElement.classList.remove('night');
    }

    this.day = !this.day;

   //BTW for some reason it does not remove the class but that's a different problem.
  }

}
```

And then on my template:

```
<div class="toggle-box" (click)="dayNight()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="toggle-box-checkbox" />
    <label for="toggle-box-checkbox" class="toggle-box-label-left"></label>
    <label for="toggle-box-checkbox" class="toggle-box-label"></label>
</div>
```

And then in less:

```
:host.night h1 {
    transition: all 1s;
        color: aliceblue;
}
```

But this works only for h1 and I'm wondering how to got other components to change with that toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service to propagate a value accross multiple components.

For instance, a service like this:

```
export class ThemeService {

    private modeSubject: BehaviorSubject<'day'|'night'> = new BehaviorSubject<'day'|'night'>('day');

    public get mode():Observable<'day'|'night'>{
        return this.modeSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public switchMode(newMode:'day'|'night'):void{
        this.modeSubject.next(newMode);
    }

}
```

And then, in your component, simply subscribe to the `mode` observable:

```
...
...
constructor(themeService: ThemeService){
    themeService.mode.subscribe(mode => this.theme = mode);
}
...
...
```

finally, use `[ngClass]` to bind the theme to your template:

Any component implementing this logic will switch with your theme mode (day or night).

Keep in mind that I used two strings here but you can use an enum for sure, these were just for the example.

Comment: yeah, i stated that I was thinking this is an overkill in a way. Each component will need to subscribe to it. I understand that its the best approach then? Thank you for a quick reply as well.

Comment: it's not overkill because the only other solution I'd see is localstorage + polling to check whether it changed or not, while 99% of the time it didn't change so you checked for nothing. Also, observable ensures full realtime reactivity which means nice UX. so yea that's definetly the best approach, plus it's easy to plug it into a new component.

That being said, don't forget to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy hook.